# IndexError: index 3650 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 3650

Tags: python

Why do i get the Out of Bounds Error?

```
t_end = 3650
TS = np.zeros(t_end)
TS[0] = 288

for tt in range(0,len(TS)):

    TS[tt+1] = TS[tt]+(deltat/cw)*((s0/4)*(1-a_earth)+(ea_new[tt]*sigma*(T_earth**4))-(sigma*TS[tt]**4))
```

Thanks already:)

I was just trying to do my Homework

Comment: The highest valid index for an array with size 3650 is 3649

Comment: TS[tt+1] on the last iteration of the loop goes out of bounds

Comment: alright, thank you:) But what do i have to change, that the last iteration doesn't go out of bounds?

Answer (score 1):

Python indexing starts at 0. As you are looping through the range of the length of array *TS*, at the last iteration you will get tt = 3649, which is the last index of the array *TS*. Since you are adding 1, it is going out of bounds at tt = 3649 as it is trying to reach the index *TS[3649 + 1]* which does not exist.

Just replace this: `TS[tt+1]` with `TS[tt]` to keep it within the bounds.

Edit:
If you'd like to set the first value to be 288 then just add the following if statement:

```
for tt in range(0,len(TS)):
    if tt == 0:
       TS[tt] = 288
    else:
        TS[tt] = TS[tt]+(deltat/cw)*((s0/4)*(1-a_earth)+(ea_new[tt]*sigma*(T_earth**4))-(sigma*TS[tt]**4))
```

Comment: okay, but then, the starting value T[0] = 288 does not go into the equation anymore

Comment: like then the first value is still 288 but the second value of TS on is not dependend on the first one anymore, right?

Comment: Sorry I didn't go through your equation earlier. I updated the code snippet now, this would set the value at index 0 to be 288.

Answer (score 0):

As you calculate the new value `TS[tt + 1]` depending on the previous one `TS[tt]`, the loop needs to end at the last-to-one position:

`for tt in range(0,len(TS) - 1):`

In addition, you have to provide a starting value `TS[0]` to be able to calculate the first value `TS[1]`, right before the loop, as `TS[0] = 0` (or whatever value is suitable).